# MySQL - on duplicate key not updating table

Tags: mysql

I have a table defined as:

```
----------------------------------------
|  a (VARCHAR)  | b (DATE) |  c (INT)  |
----------------------------------------
```

With an INDEX defined as:

```
CREATE INDEX table_index ON table (a,b);
```

When running the following code:

```
INSERT INTO test_table
        (a,b,c)
    VALUES
        ('test', '2017-10-06 08:00:00', 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        c = c + VALUES(c);
```

A new row is created each time the above query is called where I want an update operation to be done on the table instead. i.e if columns a and b are the same I want c to be updated, else a new row be created.

Why isn't the ON DUPLICATE KEY working?

Answer (score 1):

Your query will not insert new record every time if you mark **column c** as **primary key** or **unique key**.

**DUPLICATE KEY** finds duplicate primary or unique key, if it is then it'll update the same record else create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working perfectly fine here with me.

[image]